# Django runserver and memcached: variable in cache gets lost

Tags: django, memcached

In a Django website I use memcached to save a variable in cache. 
After some minutes, if I refresh the page, the variable is lost.

I am in develop mode using runserver.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cache keys are expired after some time. If you don't explicitly pass timeout to cache.set, Django will use defaul, which it retrieves from settings. If you didn't specify default timeout yourself, Django will use its own [default](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#timeout).

Comment: 300 seconds by default means 5 minutes: it's compatible with my logout times.. thank you, I'll check it immediately!